# Ace editor autocomplete uploads extra-records

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I added ui-ace editor to the my application with angular. Instead of requesting words every time, I get a json 1 time, during application initiation.

Example of json-file:

```
[
  {
    "Word": "Do {int} + {int}",
    "Meta": "Implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "Line3",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "Line2",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "Line4",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "444",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "E1",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "E2",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "E1Try",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "E3",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  },
  {
    "Word": "E4444",
    "Meta": "Not-implemented"
  }
]
```

The issue is that some of words are listed in autocomplete more than ones, take a look on a screenshot: http://take.ms/N8BFZ .
Here's how I load ace-editor, where ctrl.listStepLines is an object which contains json-response from API:

```
$scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor){
    // Editor part
    var _session = _editor.getSession();
    var _renderer = _editor.renderer;

    _editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
    _editor.setOptions({
        minLines: 10,
        maxLines: 40,
        wrap: true,
        firstLineNumber: 1,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    })

    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var rhymeCompleter = {
        getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
            if (prefix.length === 0) { callback(null, []); return }
            callback(null, ctrl.listStepLines.map(function (ea) {
                return { name: ea.Word, value: ea.Word, meta: ea.Meta }
            }));
        }
    }
    langTools.addCompleter(rhymeCompleter);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that angularjs loaded my function a lot of times and ace editor had 14 similar completers. I refactored my code and create a separate function for completer adding which is called only one time.

```
ctrl.addAutoCompleter();

        function init() {

            ctrl.addAutoCompleter = function () {
                var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
                var stepLineCompleter = {
                    getCompletions: function (_editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
                        if (prefix.length === 0) { callback(null, []); return }
                        callback(null, ctrl.listStepLines.map(function (ea) {
                            return { name: ea.Word, value: ea.Word, meta: ea.Meta }
                        }));
                    }
                }
                langTools.addCompleter(stepLineCompleter);
            }
};
```